# Redirecting Filesystem Paths via LD_PRELOAD

Tags: android, linux, libc, ld-preload

I am trying to set up a working Linux ecosystem inside an Android terminal emulator, but without actually having root access. This means that I need to adjust every reference to e.g. `/bin/sh` in the source code of every program I'm trying to compile and use.

Setting `LD_PRELOAD` before starting an application allows me to modify the behaviour of libc functions, just like fakeroot does; so I might just write a library which redirects all syscalls with absolute path names (except /dev, /sys, and /proc for example) to the folder I have write access to.

This library would have to:

- Rewrite all path names so they stay inside the fake root directory
- Nevertheless allow references from outside this directory, because e.g. `procfs` will still provide system-absolute path names
- Ensure that a child process does not accidentally unset LD_PRELOAD

But how well would this turn out? I'm no expert when it comes to low-level code, so:

- How consistently could I emulate such a "faked root directory"? Am I doomed from the beginning by the kernel which won't cooperate?
- How easy would it be for a process inside the "fake root" to accidentally break out of it? I'm not talking about deliberately trying to escape via assembler code.

**Edit:** Maybe this library could even serve as a replacement for libc, as long as I link all software I compile on that system against it?

Comment: Not doomed from the beginning, I think (fakeroot works surprisingly well for its purposes), but you already have a problem with `#!/bin/sh` in your scripts: that's the kernel who finds `/bin/sh` when you execute them. Just one extra thing to take care of in `exec*` family...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I didn' think about that.